# No puedo hacer andar los plugins sociales de facebook en mi sitio

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel, facebook

Estoy teniendo problemas con los servicios de facebook para desarrollador. 
Cuando trabajo en localhost anda bien, el tema es cuando lo testeo en el hosting (hostinger). El mas visible es la caja de comentarios que directamente no aparece. Pero el boton compartir y me gusta tampoco funcionan

La url en cuestion es emap.96.lt

En el body

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>(function(d, s, id) {
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
              js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Y en articulo:

```
<article class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <h4>{{$articulo->titulo}}</h4>
                @include('front.template.partials.face-me-gusta')
                <hr>
                <h5>{{$articulo->copete}}</h5><br>
                <img src="{{ asset('img/articulos/'.$articulo->imagen->nombre) }}" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
                <br>
                {!!$articulo->contenido!!}
                <hr>
                <h5>Si te gusto, Compartilo:</h5>
                @include('front.template.partials.face-compartir')

                <br>
                <h4>Comentarios:</h4><hr>
                <div class="fb-comments" data-href="{{'https://emap.96.lt/articulos/'.$articulo->slug}}" data-numposts="5"></div>

            </div>             

            </div>      
        </article>
```

Utilizo laravel 5.3, blade. Un slug para rutas amigables.

Desde localhost si intento imprimir la ruta. puedo hacerlo, pero cuando quiero imprimir en algun lugar la url para ver que me devuelve. No sale nada

```
{{ 'https://emap.96.lt/articulos/'.$articulo->slug }}
```

Por decantacion el problema esta en la url pienso. Pero es raro que ni siguiera pueda imprimir la url.

Comment: Ese tipo de urls generalmente las paso a través de los helpers de Laravel: `route()` si les pusiste un nombre, o url() , así lo he hecho en varios proyectos que incluyen interacción con redes sociales.

Comment: Y como seria un ejemplo en este caso utilizando una url y pasandolo como parametro el slug. porque route me va a lanzar q esa url no esta definida

Comment: Me autorespondi. {{route('front.view.articulo',$articulo->slug)}} aun asi tengo problemas

Comment: ¿Cuáles problemas sigues teniendo?

Comment: disculpen. pude solucionar lo de mostrar la caja de msj y compartir con los botones. lo cambiando el dominio del sitio compartido (insolito). Al parecer el dominio .96.lt no lo tomaba como url. pero  ahora me salta un error en el msj. pero abrire otro hilo para esto

Comment: Agrega por favor una respuesta explicando como lo solucionaste, eso puede ayudar a otras personas en el futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solucion a este problema. Aun que aun sigo sin poder hacer andar correctamente la caja de comentarios. Pero los otros componentes. como el "me gusta" o el "compartir" si.

Es un poco insolito. Pero resulta que estaba testeando en un Hosting compartido (hostinger) mi sitio y haciendo estas pruebas.

Cuando comprobé en el generador de codigo q proporciona Facebook comments, note que colocando la url del hosting (.96.lt). En la vista previa no aparecia el chat visualizado (lo mismo que pasaba en mi sitio).

Asi que se me ocurrió cambiar el dominio, aun en hostinger, pero .hol.es, y fue asi q apareció la caja de comentarios y todos los componentes andan perfectamente

Aunque los comentarios cuando quiero colocar uno, ahora me sale "Error en el mensaje"